# Could not load file or assembly 'tesseract.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to create OCR functionality using tesseract 3.02 dll. Project building successfull but run time throwing the exception like bellow error.

> *Could not load file or assembly 'tesseract.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its
>   side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application
>   event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)*

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you add `tesseract` through NuGet? Are all your references OK in Visual Studio? Where do you try to run it, in dev or production?

Comment: I have downloaded the source code of tesseract from online then added tesseract(which is provide tesseract.dll) project as a reference to my console application .

Comment: Are you trying to run the app through VS?

Comment: Yes,I'm running in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Is there a reason why you added the whole tesseract project in your solution? I would suggest you create a standalone solution for tesseract only and do a release build. Then take the .dll from the bin\release folder and add to your console app. Create an SDK folder (or whatever you want to name it), and put the dll there. Then in your console app, reference the dll from your SDK folder. This should resolve any issues.

Comment: I have tried like that also ,at the tesseract.Init line throwing the same error.

Comment: Wait a minute, you are saying that you created a separate solution with tesseract only and that you compiled successfully? You then added that dll to your console app and you are getting the same error message? Can you attach the code that calls the tessract Init() in your console app for reference?

Comment: using OCR.TesseractWrapper;                                    string TessractData = @"..\..\..\..\tessdata\";                string language = "eng";                              TesseractProcessor processor = new TesseractProcessor();             var success = processor.Init(TessractData, language, (int)eOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT);

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after the processor instantiation i.e `TesseractProcessor processor = new TesseractProcessor();` can you tell me if the processor is null or has instantiated correctly?

Comment: Can you let us know the source of your 3rd party dll? I think the tesseract-ocr.net has a dependency on VS2012 as per the documentation here: [https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract)

Comment: I have converted tesseract vs2008 source file in visual studio 2010 solution .I will work or not?

Comment: Still, you haven't told me where you got the tesseract code/dll. There must be some documentation about how to integrate with VS. Do you have a link for your download?

Comment: Actually I have downloaded tesseract3.02 setup and installed to my machine for training new tessedata for new language .so that setup itself they are providing the source code (C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract-ocr\vs2008),Now i am using the same source code in vs2010 to build dll file for my C# applicationOCR functionality.

Comment: Just now I downloaded new solution  https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract (as per your ref) in that solution sample folder contains the Tesseract.WebDemo project,Its is taking the .nuget and packages reference and working fine with my new language trained tessedata.Thank you Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to download the right references from NuGet as per the example project in GitHub https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract .

Answer (score 0):

tesseract need **tesseract.dll** and **leptonica-xy.dll** together.If leptonical does not exist side tesseract.dll you go get that error.
also for read all type of image format leptonica need **libgif libjpeg libpng libtiff zlib** but this dlls is not case error.